# Advanced Optional Parameter Searching using stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on a HRM web application.Now i have to make a Attendance Report in this application.
For this we have a advanced searching report form in this we have a EmployeeId, DateFrom and DateTo Fields to search date wise report.
I would like to use stored procedure to search the attendence report.

The problem which i face the employeeId, DateFrom and DateTo is not compalsary. But we have to search with what the given input
it may be with only employeeId, or It may with employeeId and DateFrom, Some may be employeeId, DateFrom, DateTo

I have to solve the null value when any parameter is not present when the request coming to the stored procedure
hope you understood my situation...can anyone help me...

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Employees_Search]
     @EmployeeId            Int = Null
    ,@FromDate              Date = Null
    ,@ToDate                Date = Null
AS
BEGIN

    Set Nocount On;

    Select  *
    From    dbo.Employees As e With (Nolock)
    Where   (Isnull(@EmployeeId,0) = 0 Or e.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId)
            And (@FromDate Is Null Or e.[someDateAttribute] >= @FromDate)
            And (@ToDate Is Null Or e.[someDateAttribute] <= @Todate)

END
GO
```

Comment: this is exactly what i am expecting..thak you sir...here..if we do not giving value to  DateTo parameter it will get whole data which starting from DateFrom..is there is any way to get report in that day only

Comment: Need to take a flag like @IsSameDay Varchar(1) and if the value passed as 'y' then assign dateFrom into dateTo and will work for that day only with above same query

Comment: I want a suggestion..that in the above problem table colums 'Punchin' and 'PuchOut' are varchar my code is bellow
 employeeId int=null,
 datefrom varchar=null,
 dateto varchar=null
Can i possible this operation

where(isnull(employeeId,0)=0 or ejd.recordId=employeeId)
 and (datefrom is null or ad.punchin >= datefrom)
 and (dateto is null or ad.punchout <= dateto)